# Definitions of norm of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $A,B$ be normed spaces and $F:A\rightarrow B$ a bounded linear operator.
How do I show that

> 1. $\inf\{C\geq 0:||Fa||\leq C||a||, \forall a\in A\}=\sup\{||Fa||:||a||\leq 1\}$?
> 2. $\inf\{C\geq 0:||Fa||\leq C||a||, \forall a\in A\}$ is a minimum?
> 3. Let $A\neq\{0\}$. Then $$\sup\left\{\frac{||Fa||}{||a||}, a\in A,a\neq0\right\}=\sup\{||Fa||:a\in A,||a||=1\}?$$
> 4. Why $$\sup\left\{\frac{||Fa||}{||a||}, a\in A,a\neq0\right\}=\sup\{||Fa||:a\in A,||a||=1\}=\inf\{C\geq 0:||Fa||\leq C||a||, \forall a\in A\}=\sup\{||Fa||:||a||\leq 1\}?$$

Unfortunately, I haven't the slightest clue how to begin any of these and I would really appreciate any hint to get me started.

**Edit:** Using Omnomnom's hints:
1. $$(\|Fa\| \leq C \|a\| \quad \forall a \in A) \iff (\|Fx\| \leq C \quad \forall x : \|x\| = 1)$$
The $\implies$-side seems clear. For the other way, we note that 
$||Fx||=||F\frac{y}{||y||}||=\frac{||Fy||}{||y||}\leq C$ implies $||Fy||\leq C|y||$.
3. $\sup \{\frac{||Fa||}{||a||}\}=\sup \{||F\frac{a}{||a||}||\}=\sup\{||Fx||:||x||=1\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, you'll want to show that
$$
(\|Fa\| \leq C \|a\| \quad \forall a \in A) \iff (\|Fx\| \leq C \quad \forall x : \|x\| = 1)
$$
For the second problem, the infinimum is **not** necessarily a minimum; perhaps we're missing information.  For example, the infimum **is** necessarily a minimum if $A$ is finite dimensional.

For the third (as well as the first), it helps to note that $\|F\frac{a}{\|a\|}\| = \frac{\|Fa\|}{\|a\|}$

---

Let $S_1 = \{C \geq 0 :\|Fa\| \leq C \|a\| \quad \forall a \in A\}$.  Let $S_2 = \{\|Fa\| : \|a\| \leq 1\}$.  Notably, we may rewrite $S_1 = \{C \geq 0 :\|Fa\| \leq C  \text{ whenever } \|a\| \leq 1 \}$.

Note that for every $C \in S_1$ and $M = \|Fa\| \in S_2$ (for some $a$ with $\|a\| \leq 1$), we have $C \geq \|Fa\| = M$.  Conclude that $\inf S_1 \geq \sup S_2$.

On the other hand, consider any upper bound $\alpha$ for $S_2$.  for every $a$ with $\|a\| \leq 1$, we have $\|Fa\| \in S_2$, so that $\|Fa\| \leq \alpha$.  Thus, by definition, $\alpha \in S_1$.  So, $S_1$ contains every upper bound of $S_2$.  Since the supremum is the least upper bound, $\sup S_2 \geq \inf S_1$.

Thus, $\inf S_1 = \sup S_2$ as desired.

Comment: 1. How does this prove that the inf of one is the sup of the other? 2. Why does it not work if they are both infinite dimensional? 4. Could you help with this one as well?

Comment: For 1: any $C$ from the first set is an *upper bound* for the second, and any $\|Fa\|$ from the second set is a *lower bound* to the first. Try to think about that.

Comment: For 2: think about infinite diagonal matrices, see where that gets you.  I have no idea what you're asking for 4.

Comment: Please see edit for 4, I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: @GregorSamsa I can't think of an answer other than "because of 1 and 3"

Comment: I mean the equality in the middle, why does that hold?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the $\leq$.  Show that $\sup\{||Fa||:a\in A,||a||=1\}=\sup\{||Fa||:||a||\leq 1\}$

Comment: Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: If $\|a\| < 1$, then $\|F(a/\|a\|)\| \geq \|Fa\|$

Comment: Why does this give equality of the sups?

Comment: Because for every $a$ with $\|a\| < 1$, there is a corresponding $x$ with $\|x\| = 1$ (in particular, $x = a/\|a\|$) for which $\|Fx\|$ is greater than $\|Fa\|$

Comment: I see, thanks! Also for 2, how do I show that the inf is a min if either A or B is finite dimensional?

Comment: In fact, we specifically need $A$ to be finite dimensional.  One way to see this is to note that in finite dimensions, the closed unit ball is compact.

Comment: Since $A$ still contains $0$ for 1., can we still say $\sup\{||Fa||:||a||=1\}=\sup\{||Fa||:||a||\leq 1\}$?

Comment: (Ah, you mean part 1.) Yes, that equality holds for any linear $F$ over any normed space.

Comment: And I still find the 'inf=sup' concept a bit vague. Am I supposed to show sup$\leq$inf and inf$\leq$sup?

Comment: @GregorSamsa see my latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to Sec.2.7 in the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwin Kreyszig.

That section defines what a bounded linear operator is and answers all of your questions.